# Script keeps giving an error using moveTo since .addFile was depreciated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Since google depreciated .addFile (thanks so much for that,) I'm trying to use the new moveTo to move a created file into a specific folder.  I keep getting the following error:

*Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.moveTo.*

I have the code snippet below.  Can anyone help me out and show me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much!!

```
 var dailyFolder = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Created Folders");
    var docFolder = dailyFolder.getRange("B3").getValue(); // this year's individual document folder.
  
  var newDocId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateDocId).makeCopy().getId();
  
//  DriveApp.getFolderById(docFolder).addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(newDocId)); // depreciated but still works.

   DriveApp.getFileById(newDocId).moveTo(docFolder); // keep getting the error here.
```

Edit:  Added the following line:

```
const targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(docFolder)
```

Changed the moveTo to:

```
DriveApp.getFileById(newDocId).moveTo(targetFolder);
```

and I get the following information: targetFolder is: Individual Docs (2023-24)

It looks like instead of using the id number from cell B3, it is somehow using the name of the folder?

Comment: `docFolder` is a string.  You need to get the `Folder` with that name for `moveTo()`

Comment: wait.. what do you mean?  I have it pulling the folder id from a cell on the spreadsheet.  The folder id changes every day (M-F).  How do I get the ID to pass through?

Comment: It's pulling the name of the folder, not the ID..

Comment: Is it the folder name or ID in the sheet cell?

Comment: When I created the folder, I told the program to put the ID in cell B3.  Just made an edit to the above post showing a new snippet of code that's giving me the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**SUGGESTION:**

You could use [getFolderById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid) to get the `Folder Object` for the `moveTo` method as such.

**Example:**

NOTE: The `sheetId` and `folderId` are just dummy files/folders so I wouldn't mind sharing in this example.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetId = '1xFGeiNMEkBQNCw0VBgXCWBVBVaqYJUuqjVn72C_Q9PU';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1kPis2Ss3UQSGhJG1NUNq0GQZmCaaIB0T'); 
  DriveApp.getFileById(sheetId).moveTo(folder);
}
```

Comment: That didn't work either.. It's pulling the name of the folder, not the ID # that I need.  The ID# is pasted in cell B3.

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the suggestion of Century Tuna.

```
let dailyFolder = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Created Folders");
let docFolder = dailyFolder.getRange("B3").getValue(); // this year's individual document folder.
  
let newDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateDocId).makeCopy();  // returns the copy
let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(docFolder);
  
newDoc.moveTo(folder);
```

Comment: perfect!! Thank you so much!